# ViewModel does not trigger observer of mutablelivedata

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata, observer-pattern

I have the following ViewModel class -

```kotlin
class VerifyOtpViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var existingUserProfileData: MutableLiveData<TwoVerteUsers.TwoVerteUser>? = null

    fun checkInfoForAuthenticatedUser(authorization: String, user: String) {
        ProfileNetworking.getUsersProfiles(authorization, GetUserProfilesBodyModel(listOf(user)), object : ProfileNetworking.OnGetUserProfilesListener {
            override fun onSuccess(model: TwoVerteUsers) {
                existingUserProfileData?.value = model[0]
            }

            override fun onError(reason: String) {
                Log.d("existingProfile", reason)
            }
        })
    }

    fun getExistingUserProfileData(): LiveData<TwoVerteUsers.TwoVerteUser>? {
        if (existingUserProfileData == null) return null
        return existingUserProfileData as LiveData<TwoVerteUsers.TwoVerteUser>
    }
}
```

and the following observer -

```kotlin
private fun initViewModel() {
        verifyOtpViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(VerifyOtpViewModel::class.java)
        verifyOtpViewModel.getExistingUserProfileData()?.observe(this, Observer {
            if (it != null)
                Log.d("existingProfile", it.username)
        })
    }
```

For some reason the observe is never triggered even after the MutableLiveData object is being given a value

Tried to search for a solution here at stackoverflow but nothing helped

what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refactor your code to this, and you should be good to go:

```
class VerifyOtpViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _existingUserProfileData = MutableLiveData<TwoVerteUsers.TwoVerteUser>()
    val existingUserProfileData: LiveData<TwoVerteUsers.TwoVerteUser>
        get() = _existingUserProfileData

    fun checkInfoForAuthenticatedUser(authorization: String, user: String) {
        ProfileNetworking.getUsersProfiles(
            authorization,
            GetUserProfilesBodyModel(listOf(user)),
            object : ProfileNetworking.OnGetUserProfilesListener {
                override fun onSuccess(model: TwoVerteUsers) {
                    existingUserProfileData.value = model[0]
                }

                override fun onError(reason: String) {
                    Log.d("existingProfile", reason)
                }
            })
    }
}
```

And observing:

```
verifyOtpViewModel.existingUserProfileData.observe(this, Observer {
   .....
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much, solved. Can you please explain what was the issue so I can learn from it?

Comment: `  if (existingUserProfileData == null) return null`, first you never initialized your observable